# Why does Ice Bear talk in the third person?

Tags: we-bare-bears

In **We Bare Bears** one of the three bear brothers, Ice Bear talks in the third person, typically limited to the form of *"Ice Bear something something"*. He (almost) always starts his sentences with ***"Ice Bear"***, in the third person, when he talks that is. He also talks less than the other two brothers. Why?

Comment: Not sure if this is 100% the answer so leaving as a comment, but in the Original Comic that We Bare Bears is based off of, the Ice Bear character in that comic also talks in the third person. As such, it may just be a holdover from the comic.

Comment: There should still be a reason behind it. And I didn't know it was a comic. Neat.

Comment: http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/webarebears/images/3/3f/Ttbb1.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150627114718 that's the first one he produced. You can see the rest here: http://webarebears.wikia.com/wiki/The_Three_Bare_Bears

Comment: i think it has something to do with his back story